# I am old, and I am fast

Tags: riddle

> I am old, and I am fast.
>
> I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.
>
> I never take the easy way.
>
> You run with me right now.

What am I?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

my answer is

> assembly language!

I am old, and I am fast.

> assembly dates back to the beginnings of computing

I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.

> it is one of the lowest level programming languages you can find

I never take the easy way.

> it is a very difficult language

You run with me right now.

> and your running it on your computer as we speak

Comment: most likely not the answer, but +1 for thinking outside the box

Comment: Well, the question is by JavaProphet...

Comment: Why is it "most likely not the answer"? Sounds like a pretty good answer to me.

Comment: Lots of great answers, but this is the correct one.

Comment: I don't get the "you run with me right now". Binaries are in _machine code_, *not* assembly language. Strictly speaking they're as different as C and machine code, except that assembly is closer to a one-to-one, direct-translation relationship with machine code (but not 100%). As far as I know, at least.

Comment: Looking at this years later, I just noticed the last part isnt correct.  "You run with me right now."  No one **runs** assembly language, its is **compiled**  into an executable binary and that is what is run.

Answer (score 22):

The answer is:

> my shadow

I am old, and I am fast.

> your shadow has been around as long as you have, shadows always keep up with you

I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.

> Since light often comes from above, shadows stay on the ground

I never take the easy way.

> shadows will fall on any terrain, even difficult

You run with me right now.

> your shadow follows you everywhere

Answer (score 7):

The answer is:

> Water

I am old, and I am fast.

> Water is old because most of it is never destroyed just vaporizes and condenses again and again.
>  Water is fast in rivers, waterfalls, rain, etc.

I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.

> Water always flows down from heights (like mountains).
>  Another reason: Water changes to the ice in heights and so it dislike heights.

I never take the easy way.

> Water can flow in narrow and difficult paths. Water can reach to non-accessible spaces between rocks, etc. And if it was in a easy way like flat road, it will lose its continuity and will vaporize easier.

You run with me right now.

> Most part of our body is water and without it, we cannot continue the life.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is

> Energy

I am old, and I am fast.

> Energy is as old as the universe, and is fast (reference to kinetic energy maybe?)

I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.

> Things will always try to move to a lower energy state. I dislike heights could be an example of gravitational energy (gravity being my other possible answer)

I never take the easy way.

> By imparting energy, you are inputting work. Not easy!

You run with me right now.

> Without energy, you probably wouldn't be running very far!

Answer (score 4):

Never used spoilers so hope it worked

> The Earth

I am old, and I am fast.

> 4.5 Billion Years old and moving around the sun at 30 km/sec

I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.

> Can't get much lower than that

I never take the easy way.

> Flying through space, anything can collide into it

You run with me right now.

> We are on the planet

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! A very good answer.. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You are...

> Problems

I am old, and I am fast.

> Problems are as old as time itself, and they pile up faster than accomplishments.

I prefer to stay low, I dislike heights.

> People with problems are in a low period of their life - depression, sadness, anguish, grief.  While those who are on a 'high' don't notice their problems at all.

I never take the easy way.

> Solving a problem is never easy - you just create more problems.

You run with me right now.

> Everybody has problems - it's a fact of life.